# How to fix this error in selenium: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_css_selector'

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

how to fix `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_css_selector'` Error in Python Using Selenium

Here is my code:

```
for s in site:
    time.sleep(3)
    URL = 'https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3a' + str(site) + '&qs=n&sp=-1&pq=site%3a' + str(site) + '&sc=0-22&sk=&cvid=D38F613A00C64A88B2C0F87BD653088A&first=' + str(url_p)     
    driver.get(URL)

    title = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
    link = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('h2')
    link.find_elements_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
```

## EDIT

Link: [site](https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Alocalbitcoins.com&qs=n&sp=-1&pq=site%3Alocalbitcoins.com&sc=0-22&sk=&cvid=D38F613A00C64A88B2C0F87BD653088A&first=0)

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find_elements_by_css_selector('a') will returns as list not element.
```

Change this line.

```
link.find_elements_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
```

to

```
link.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
```

**Edited**:

```
URL ="https://www.bing.com/search?q=site%3Alocalbitcoins.com&qs=n&sp=-1&pq=site%3Alocalbitcoins.com&sc=0-22&sk=&cvid=D38F613A00C64A88B2C0F87BD653088A&first=0"
driver.get(URL)
for link in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h2>a"):
    print(link.text + "," + link.get_attribute('href'))
```

Comment: error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\bing.py", line 24, in <module>
    link.find_element_by_css_selector('a').get_attribute('href')
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'`

Comment: Change the previous link variable as well.

Comment: Error: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\bing.py", line 29, in <module>
    s.write(str(title[i].text) + ',' + str(link[i]) + '\n')
TypeError: 'FirefoxWebElement' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: can you share your link?

Answer (score 0):

Please find below answer

```
elementText = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a")))
    for element in elementText:
       print(element.get_attribute('href'))
```

please dont forget to import

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
links = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('a')
for l in links:
   print(l.get_attribute('href'))
```